# How to print this code to HTML?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I'm new to programming. I'm using an API to out put the result on browser using node.js. The API works fine on console.log but I want to render it on browser. I'm using jade temple. so how do I write the code for rendering on browser instead of console.log? Sorry for my English!!

```
var express = require('express'),
    app     = express();

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    // res.send('index.html');
    res.render('index');
});


var messagebird = require('messagebird')('access key gores here');

messagebird.balance.read(function (err, response) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log('Your balance: ' + response.amount + ', ' + response.type + ', ' + response.payment);
  // document.getElementById('#balance').innerHTML = Your balance: 'response.amount';
});
```

Comment: Copy paste that code into the `app.get` block and replace `console.log(...)` with `res.end(...)`? But what you need is probably a REST API.

Comment: use document.write instead of console.log or document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML = 'Your balance: '+ response.amount;

Comment: `jade` is now named `pug`. Your view engine might not be getting set correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you guys!! anyway I figued it out this is the code that works fine.

```
 app.get('/',function(req,res) {
   messagebird.balance.read(function (err, response) {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err);
  } else
       res.render('index', {
        balance:response.amount, type:response.type
       });
    });   
 });
```

and just write this code  in your views template index file, like that
if you are using jade.
h1= balance.

Thanks a lot **@Umakant Mane**

Answer (score 3):

try this...

```
    app.get('/',function(req,res) {
   messagebird.balance.read(function (err, response) {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err);
  } else
       res.render('index',{balance:response.amount, type:response.type});
    });   
 });
```

Comment: I tried your code, no error from nodemon like I had before but still nothing  display on the browser but if I try console.log I get the balance. do you think I'm still doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you saying. I don't have any code on my index.jade. I removed all code just to be able to see the output! please

Comment: Can you more specific about what you saying I just didn't get it!!